# Is there possibility to compress audio and video file in android programmatically?

Tags: android, video, audio, compression

As I record the video file for 1min it take 3mb of size as i want to post this file to server it is taking more time.So I need to decrease the time by compassing the recorded video file and send it to server.Is there possibility to compress the video file programmatically.
Thanks in advance.
Teja.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that simply compressing it with some zip-algorithm (relatively easy to do in Java) wouldn't help you much. Try compressing the file yourself. (If it *did* make the file smaller, it would most likely already be a part of the video-file format, wouldn't it :-)

If you want to compress the video, you have to re-encode it with a **lower bit-rate / lower resolution** or something similar.

Comment: hi aioobe how can I re-encode the recorded video with a lower bit-rate / lower resolution.please can you suggest me with any link related to it.

Comment: Honestly and unfortunately, no. I have no experience of doing so programatically. I'd suggest you google for *android transcode video* or *android encode video*