# may I set file size when user click the submit upload server before?

Tags: php, android, upload, retrofit

may I set file size when user click the submit upload server before?

If the video file size is over 10MB then the file is cannot choose or cannot upload, so how can I do?

this is my code

```
private void selectVideo() {
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.setType("video/*");
        intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
        startActivityForResult(intent, VIDEO);
    }

if(requestCode == VIDEO){
                image.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                previewImageView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                //video.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                contentURI = data.getData();
                videoPath = getFilePathFromContentUri(contentURI, getContentResolver());
                Glide.with(this).load(contentURI).into(previewImageView);
                video.setVideoURI(contentURI);
                video.requestFocus();
                //video.start();
                MediaController mc= new MediaController(UploadActivity.this);
                video.setMediaController(mc);
                check_video = "ok";
            }

private void uploadFile() {
        progressDialog.show();

Map<String, RequestBody> map = new HashMap<>();
            //File file = new File(newvideoPath);
            String fullFilePath = PathUtil.getPathFromUri(this,contentURI);
            // Parsing any Media type file
            File file = new File(fullFilePath);
            String filename = getID+ "_"+ fullFilePath.substring(fullFilePath.lastIndexOf("/")+1);

            RequestBody requestBody = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("*/*"), file);
            map.put("file\"; filename=\"" + file.getName() + "\"", requestBody);
            ApiConfig getResponse = AppConfig.getApiClient().create(ApiConfig.class);
            Call<ServerResponse> call = getResponse.upload("token", map,imageName,userID,sp2,tag);
            call.enqueue(new Callback<ServerResponse>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(Call<ServerResponse> call, Response<ServerResponse> response) {
                    if (response.isSuccessful()){
                        if (response.body() != null){
                            progressDialog.dismiss();
                            ServerResponse serverResponse = response.body();
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), serverResponse.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            Intent intent = new Intent(UploadActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
                            startActivity(intent);
                            finish();
                        }
                    }else {

                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "problem uploading video", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onFailure(Call<ServerResponse> call, Throwable t) {

                    Log.v("Response gotten is", t.getMessage());
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "problem uploading video " + t.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                }
            });
```

I have tried to set on php, but that is not my want, I hope I can setting on the uploadActivity. If the file size over 10MB then the use cannot choose the file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's how you can know your file size, then you can play with it.

```
File file = new File(fullFilePath);
long length = file.length();
length = length/1024;
Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Video size:"+length+"KB",
Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

Comment: hi guys, do u know how can compress video ? I mean, when the user upload video, how can compress and  reduce video quality? I just know image methods

Comment: Please refer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57983099/how-to-reduce-video-size-with-java-kotlin-on-android